# How can I retry a AWS CloudFormation update if an update is already happening?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Trying to implement CI, every commit will trigger a CFN update. How can I check if an update is happening and force my script to wait or schedule some retry at a future time?

I see there's a describe-stack-events, but this gives me a list not the most recent event. Is there a shortened version?

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --profile dev --stack-name name --max-items 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name name --profile dev
```

More details at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/index.html#cli-aws-cloudformation-wait

Answer (score 2):

The one-liner I use when I'm testing scripts (and assuming that there will be failures).  It runs the script, waits for the update to complete, then returns the event which caused the problem.

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name name --template-body file://stack.yaml && aws cloudformation wait stack-update-complete --stack-name name || aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name name | grep -B2 -A8 CREATE_FAILED
```